# Find if a date is in date range using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I have following values stored in MySQL table:

```
--- ------------------------     -------------------
Id | StartDate (VARCHAR (20))  | EndDate(VARCHAR(20))
--- ------------------------     -------------------
1  | 03-04-2017                | 18-04-2017
```

I am using the following SQL to find if the date is within the StartDate and EndDate:

```
SELECT 
(date_format(str_to_date('03-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') >= StartDate 
AND 
date_format(str_to_date('03-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') <= EndDate) AS 
valid 
FROM holiday
```

My issue is it that when I execute the query and provide 03-04-2017 it returns 1 but also returns 1 when I provide 03-05-2017.

Could someone please highlight what is wrong in this query?

Comment: what datatype have the field ? VARCHAR or DATE ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thanks they both are varchar and unfortunately I cannot change schema.

Comment: You need to convert the string to a date

Comment: @juergend Thanks but doesn't this convert string to date .. date_format(str_to_date('03-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y')

Comment: first of all you should really consider converting your table from `varchar` to `date`. it's ridiculous you store date in varchar non iso format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM holiday
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(StartDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
BETWEEN 
    str_to_date('03-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
AND
    str_to_date('03-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y');
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT IF(STR_TO_DATE('11-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
    ->             BETWEEN
    ->                 str_to_date('03-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
    ->             AND
    ->                 str_to_date('10-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
    ->
    -> ,'YES','NO') AS ANSWER;
+--------+
| ANSWER |
+--------+
| NO     |
+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(STR_TO_DATE('04-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
    ->             BETWEEN
    ->                 str_to_date('03-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
    ->             AND
    ->                 str_to_date('10-04-2017','%d-%m-%Y')
    ->
    -> ,'YES','NO') AS ANSWER;
+--------+
| ANSWER |
+--------+
| YES    |
+--------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to find if the "given" date is between "StartDate" and the "EndDate". Your solution  returns records between these dates. For example it should return Yes  if the date is 04-04-2017 and No if the date is 19-04-2017 as it is not between StartDate and EndDate.

Comment: i have add a sample in my answer, so you only must put it in the field section

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN` operator to compare the dates, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE '2017-04-03' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

**Update**

If the dates are stored as `varchar` then you need to convert it to `date` before comparing, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE '2017-04-03' BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/580ced/1/0)**.

Comment: It is stored as string and not in the format you use either

Comment: @juergend noticed the update to the question after posting the answer. Chaged now.

Answer (score 1):

All other answers are good for your question but in my opinion you should convert your database.

**It's only sane option.**

Using dates in weird `VARCHAR` format will have big impact in future. Not only it impacts perfomances of your tables right now but you are missing whole MySQL date API ecosystem because of it.

1. Add temporary columns let's say `tmp_start_time DATE`
2. Fill them with dates `UPDATE holiday SET tmp_start_time = str_to_date(start_time,'%d-%m-%Y')`
3. Drop old varchar keys in table
4. Add same keys but as `DATE`
5. Update them `UPDATE holiday SET start_time = tmp_start_time`

From now on you would be able to use `BETWEEN` as everyone else without str_to_date

---

I just found your comment

> unfortunately I cannot change schema

ask yourself twice: are you sure?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I agree 100%, but in my situation I have inherited this application and I am under instructions to not change the schema as it might break some reports.